# Definition of tensor product of graded maps

Tags: linear-algebra, monoidal-categories, graded-modules

The tensor product  of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces $V = \bigoplus_iV_i$ and $W = \bigoplus_iW_i$ is
$$
V\otimes W = \bigoplus_i(V\otimes W)_i,
$$
where
$$
(V\otimes W)_i=\bigoplus_{j\leq i}(V_j\otimes V_{i-j}).
$$
Hence $V_i\otimes W_j\subset (V\otimes W)_{i+j}$.
The tensor product of graded maps $f,g:V\to W$ must then satisfy
$$
(f\otimes g)(v_i\otimes v_j) \in \bigoplus_{k\leq i+j}(W_k\otimes W_{i+j-k}).
$$
A natural definition would be
$$
(f\otimes g)(v_i\otimes v_j) = f(v_i)\otimes g(v_j)\in (W\otimes W)_{i+j}.
$$
However, the usual definition for the tensor product of graded maps has an additional minus sign:
$$
(f\otimes g)(v_i\otimes v_j) = (-1)^{|f||g|}f(v_i)\otimes g(f_j).
$$
Why is the minus sign there in the usual definition?